# Any gcc options to allow ((int *)p)++

Tags: c, gcc

Some C compilers can sometimes deduce a casted pointer as still a lvalue, but gcc defaults won't compile it. Instead of having to **port** (by **human**-error-prone way)**legacy** code base to:

```
p=(int *)p+1 ; /* increment by sizeof(int) */
```

can **gcc** be made to allow this code below (even if not technically correct)?

```
void f() {
    void *p ; /* type to be cast later for size */
    ((int *)p)++ ; /* gcc -c f.c => lvalue required error */ }
```

---

Edit: even if technically incorrect, I assume the only programmer intent for such code is for `p` to remain lvalue and "increment" it, generating same code as my long form, right? (*perreal* flagged as "lvalue cast")

Edit2: We all agree refactoring to std C is best, but if something like *Mateo*'s `-fpermissive` worked, it might not catch future programming errors, but hoping **initial** gcc porting effort will be less faulty... Any other similar suggestions?

Comment: This used to be supported by GCC (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386485/why-isnt-the-result-of-this-cast-an-lvalue) but not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean up your code(remove excessive casts) , you can concentrate the ugly casts inside a macro or, even better, an inlined function.
The below fragment only makes  use of *implicit* casts to/from `void*`

You are ,of course, still responsible for the proper alignment.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void *increment(void * p,size_t offset)
{
char *tmp = p;
return tmp+offset;
}

int main(void)
{
void *ptr = "Hell0 world!\n";

ptr = increment( ptr, sizeof(int) );

printf("%s", (char*) ptr);

return 0;
}
```